# "expected indented block" error in code?

Tags: python

I m getting "expected indented block" error in below code : i am new to python please help

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"My Frame", size=(300,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
        wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"POS:",pos=(10, 12))
        self.PosCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,"",pos=(40, 10))

        def OnMove(self, event):
            pos = event.GetPosition()
            Self.PosCtrl.SetValue("%s, %s" % (pos.x,pos.y))

            if __name__ == '__main__':
            app = wx.PySimpleApp
            frame = MyFrame()
            frame.Show(True)
            app.MainLoop
```

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if _    name__ == ’__main__’:` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Answer (score 5):

Your indenting is completely strange, this is my best guess. I would suggest to try and learn Python more from the basics up.

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"My Frame", size=(300,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
        wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"POS:",pos=(10, 12))
        self.PosCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,"",pos=(40, 10))

    def OnMove(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        Self.PosCtrl.SetValue("%s, %s" % (pos.x,pos.y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop
```

Comment: The stuff under `if __name__ == '__main__':` is double indented, so I'd move them back one level and it'll be golden methinks.

Comment: Ahh, you posted the comment while I still was editing, thought you were talking about the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably indent the code below `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you pasted
you need to de indent the OnMove and fix the if **name**

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the "if" block :)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.PySimpleApp
        frame = MyFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        app.MainLoop
```

This is the indentation error :)

Edit: i posted you the solution :)

Comment: Three smileys in one answer? Seriously? Perhaps you should start ending sentences with a dot instead of a smiley.

Comment: I was trying to be educate with user... It's seem to be that you don't know what "education" is...

Comment: I very well know what education is, and you should back off a bit. I simply gave you a tip that will give people a better impression of you on the internet and you instantly attack me on something completely unrelated.